# confusing with c string array with point and negative indexes

Tags: c

in the following code (final exam) , the position of cpp pointer don't change, so, how cpp[-1][-1] == cpp [0][0] ?

```
char *c[]={"ENTER", "NEW", "POINT", "FIRST"};
char **cp[]={c+3,c+2,c+1,c}; // FIRST, POINT, NEW, ENTER
char ***cpp=cp;             // FIRST,POINT,NEW,ENTER 

int main()
{
  ++cpp;        // POINT
  ++cpp;        // NEW
 
  printf("cpp[0][0]     %s \n" , cpp [0][0]);           // NEW
 
  // how is cpp [-1][-1] == cpp [0][0]
   printf("cpp [-1][-1]     %s \n" , cpp [-1][-1]);     // NEW 
            
  // how is cpp [0][1] == POINT
  printf("cpp [0][1]        %s \n" , cpp [0][1]);       //POINT
   
  printf("cpp [-1][-1]+1        %s \n" , cpp [-1][-1]+1);//EW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cp` is an array. `char ***cpp=cp;` sets `cpp` to point to the first element of that array, `cp[0]`.

`++cpp;` increments `cpp`, so it points to `cp[1]`.

`++cpp;` increments `cpp` again, so it points to `cp[2]`.

Then `cp[-1]` is, by definition `*(cp + -1)`. Since `cp` points to `cp[2]`, `cp + -1` points to `cp[1]`. Then `*(cp + -1)` is `cp[1]`.

`char **cp[]={c+3,c+2,c+1,c};` initialized `cp[1]` to `c+2`, which is a pointer to `c[2]`.  So `cp[1]` points to `c[2]`.

Now we have figured out `cpp[-1]` points to `c[2]`, so `cpp[-1][-1]` is `(&c[2])[-1]`. Again by definition, `(&c[2])[-1]` is `*(&c[2] + -1)`. Since `&c[2]` points to `c[2]`, `&c[2] + -1` points to `c[1]`. So `*(&c[2] + -1)` is `c[1]`.

`char *c[]={"ENTER", "NEW", "POINT", "FIRST"};` initialized `c[1]` to point to the first character of `"NEW"`.

So `cpp[-1][-1]` is `c[1]` which points to the first character of `"NEW"`. Passing this pointer to `printf` for `%s` prints “NEW”.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I viewed the problem:

For any double pointer of the type `Type** ptr`,

```
ptr[x][y] == *(*(ptr + x) + y) //#1
```

Using this for your problem:

```
cpp[-1][-1] == *(*(cpp -1) -1)
```

Now, we're given this before the start of the `main()`

```
cpp = cp //Both are of type char***
```

Thus, when `main()` executes these statements,

```
cpp++; cpp++;
```

`cpp` is moved to ***point to*** `cp[2]`, or

```
cpp == &cp[2] //cp[2] is of type char**, so &cp[2] is char*** The types still hold
```

Also,

```
cpp - 1 == &cp[1] //cp[1] is of type char**, so same type as above
```

Because, `cpp` as a `char***` pointer ***points to*** `cp[2]` memory block, decrementing that means moving it to point one block before i.e to `cp[1]`

Using this in the above `#1`:

```
cpp[-1][-1] == *(*(cpp-1) -1) == *(*(&cp[1]) - 1) == *( cp[1] -1 ) //#2
```

Here the quivalence `*(&x) == x` is used. Now,

```
cp[1] == c+2 //cp[x] is of type char**, c is of type char**, so is c + 2, thus types are again fine
```

Thus replacing this in `#2`,

```
*( cp[1] -1 ) == *( c + 2 -1) == *(c + 1) = c[1] == "NEW"
```

Also, using the same equivalence of `#1`, we have

```
cpp[0][0] == *( *(cpp + 0) + 0) == *(*(cpp)
```

Since we haven't actually changed `cpp`, it still points to `&cp[2]`, so

```
*(*cpp) == *(*(&cp[2])) == *(cp[2]) == *(c + 1) == c[1] == "NEW"
```

At each step, one has to always ensure that the types on both sides of `==` always match, else the pointer arithmetic would go awry and lead to an incorrect solution.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation, I understand it.